# MySQL: return list of users ids with condition

Tags: mysql

I have table "battle_user" manage relation between battles and users tables

table "battle_user" structure:

```
battle_id     user_id
1111            1
1111            2
22              1
22              3
3               2
3               3
```

how to reutrn list of "user_id" that have battle with specific user,
like return list of user ids have battle with user_id = 1

result should be:

```
user_id
2
3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a query:

```
select distinct(b.user_id)
from battle_user b
inner join battle_user b2 on b.battle_id = b2.battle_id and b2.user_id = 10
where b.user_id <> 10
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT distinct(user_id) FROM battle_user
WHERE battle_id IN (select battle_id from battle_user where user_id = 1) and user_id <> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as

```
select 
b1.user_id from battle_user b1 
where b1.user_id<>1 
and exists ( 
  select 1 from battle_user b2 
  where 
  b2.battle_id = b1.battle_id 
  and  b2.user_id = 1
);
```